# range(1,1) is not processed by loop

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I was trying to loop product's quantity:

```
{% for the_number in one_product.product_stock_range %}
    {% if the_number == one_product.quantity %}
    <option value="{{ the_number }}" selected="selected">{{ the_number }}</option>
    {% else %}
    <option value="{{ the_number }}">{{ the_number }}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

now i am using

```
  'product_stock_range'   : range(1, product_stock),
```

but sometimes, some product's stock is only 1. The loop will not run, how to i solve this issue? how do i force the loop to run even when it's only one-time loop?

Comment: how can you make a loop continue when you all also know there is just one range the loop will go?

Comment: It looks like you want the count to go from 1 to the number of products, not 0 to n-1 products. That is, counting, not indexing. Correct?

Comment: correct tdelaney

Comment: Then I think you've got another bug. Isn't the last product always missing, not just when there is 1?

Comment: the issue is when the stock of that product in the backend is only 1, the loop will not run at all on the frontend, so the form quantity shows an empty form.

Comment: What if there are 2 products? Won't the form only show 1?

Comment: well true, that's kinda a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a conditional:

```
range(1, product_stock if product_stock > 1 else 2)
```

this, in the case that `product_stock` is `1`, yields a `range(1, 2)` which results in a single iteration (which is what you say you need).

Comment: That's a non-obvious way to do `range(1, product_stock+1)` and introduces a bug when `product_stock == 0` (erroneously claiming there is 1).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change `range(1, product_stock)` to `range(0, product_stock)` or `range(product_stock)` for short (the default is zero), since indexing starts at 0 for most programming languages, including Python.

Comment: That counts from zero but I think OP wants to count from 1 like people do.

Comment: I suppose the OP might've want to count from 1, but he never specified that, until after in the comments. The logical way is usually to start counting from 0...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bug for all product counts, its just more pronounced when count is 1. Suppose you have 4 products, `range(1, 4)` only counts `1, 2, 3`. That's because `range` is open... it doesn't include the terminating number. You are always displaying one too few products, its just most pronounced when count is 1. The normal way to solve this is

```
 'product_stock_range'   : range(1, product_stock+1),
```